# Asp.net User Login Count and LastLogin

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, authentication

Is the normal way to do this to just make 2 cols in my User table, loginCount and lastLogin, and then when a user is Authenticated hit the db and update them in the code behind?

I am using OpenID only.

**Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same solution and it works for me (and my clients, too) :)

Answer (score 1):

Look into the asp.net membership provider it does everything for you.

Comment: I want to use OpenID exclusively. =(

Comment: .Net Membership has a login count?  It definitely has a last login date - but I haven't seen a count?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not considered Built-in Security Features for Memberships and Roles management, have a look at these tutorials. What you are about to start working on, might have already been implemented.

- [**Asp.Net Security Tutorials**](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/)